# What's the value of two digits from a certain number composed by six digits when it comes from a prime?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cryptarithm

The problem is as follows:

> The number $\overline{ab0ab0}$ is the result of the product between
> two consecutive prime numbers. Assuming the $0$ in the number
> represents zero. Find the value of $\overline{ab}$

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&38\\
2.&85\\
3.&51\\
4.&34\\
4.&17\\
\end{array}$

In my attempt to solve this problem I was only able to spot this by decomposing the six number digit as follows using base-10.

$\overline{ab0ab0}=10^5a+10^4b+10^3 \times 0+10^2a+10b+0=100100a+10010b$

Then I could note this can be rearranged as follows:

$10010(10a+b)$

Upon performing a canonical decomposition in the number I could spot that:

$10010= 2 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13$

Had this question asked all those I would have landed in the answer. But that's where I'm stuck. Can someone help me from here?.

Am I heading in the right direction with this approach?. It would help me a lot if someone could help me from where I had came stuck.

Comment: How could the product of 2 primes end in a 0?

Comment: (Apart from 2*5 of course)

Comment: As you have it, your question is a non-question. It has no well-defined answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem makes some sense if we drop the word "two" and ask for just "a product of consecutive prime numbers".  In such a case, having derived

$10010=2×5×7×11×13$

we observe that $3$ is missing.  We multiply that in to get $30030$, which does not qualify because that would require the initial digit $a$ to be zero.  To remove that blockage, try introducing the next prime factor, $17$, to get

$2×3×5×7×11×13×17=\color{blue}{51}0\color{blue}{51}0$.